# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - sid

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: 1,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
          }
        };
```

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: 1,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        /*#region responsive code begin*/

        var MAX_WIDTH = 980;

        function ScaleSlider() {
            var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
            var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;

            if (containerWidth) {

                var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);

                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(expectedWidth);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        /*#endregion responsive code end*/
    });
```

Can any one correct me as i am getting the above error in console

Comment: Fix the indentation (and format) and you should find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of your question is a little messed up, but it appears you have two adjacent `jQuery document.ready` code blocks. The first one, however, is not properly terminated. If you add a `});` after the first block (i.e. right before the *second* `jQuery(document).ready(function ($)`) then the brackets and parentheses all line up.

- **Syntax Error**:  your code syntax is messed up, i.e. you arent following the rules of the language
- **Unexpected End of Input**:  the syntax parser was expecting to see something closed out, that wasn't (i.e. a `}` )

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)